# Count of values in intervals of latitude and years

Tags: r, count

I have different dataframes with a column in which there are the latitudes (latitude) of some records and in another column of the same dataframe the date of the records (datecollected).
I would like to count and export in a new dataframe the number of the records in the same intervals of latitude (5 degrees) and year (two years).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Hint: you'll make it easier for us to answer by providing some sample data.)

```
dataset <- data.frame(datecollected=
  sample(as.Date("2000-01-01")+(0:3650),1000,replace=TRUE),
latitude=90*runif(1000))
```

We round the `datecollected` down to the next even year:

```
year.index <- (as.POSIXlt(dataset$datecollected)$year %/% 2)*2+1900
```

Similarly, we round the `latitude` down to the nearest multiple of 5 degrees:

```
latitude.index <- (floor(dataset$latitude) %/% 5)*5
```

Then we simply build a `table` on the rounded years and latitudes:

```
table(year.index,latitude.index)

          latitude.index
year.index  0  5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50 55 60 65 70 75 80 85
      2000 12  9 15  7 11 10 11 14  9 13 11 10  8 11 13 25 10 18
      2002 11  9 11 16 11 15 12  5 12 13  7 15  8  7 11  7 10 13
      2004  8 12  9 10 12 16 12 13  9  7 16 11  6 13  4 15 12 10
      2006 14  8 13 10 12  9 12  9  6 11 11  9 13  9 10  5  5 12
      2008  8 12 17 12 12  8 12  8 14 12 11 11 10 10 14 16 17 13
```

---

EDIT: after a bit of discussion in the comments, I'll post my current script. It seems like there may be an issue when you read the data into R. This is what I do and what I get:

```
rm(list=ls())
dataset <- read.csv("GADUS.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",")
year.index <- (as.POSIXlt(as.character(dataset$datecollected),format="%Y-%m-%d")$year
  %/% 2)*2+1900
latitude.index <- (floor(dataset$latitude) %/% 5)*5
table(year.index,latitude.index)

          latitude.index
year.index     0     5    20    35    40    45    50    55    60    65    70    75
      1752     0     0     0     0     0    20     0     0     0     0     0     0
      1754     0     0     0     0     0    27     0     3     0     0     0     0
      1756     0     0     0     0     0    21     0     1     0     0     0     0
      1758     0     0     0     0     0    46     0     2     0     0     0     0
...
```

Does this give the same result for you? If not, please edit your question and post the result of `str(dataset[,c("datecollected","latitude")])`.

Comment: Great, It seems to work but I do not understand why date begins in 2000 and ends in 2008, even if my records begin in 1800 and end in the 2000s. In other words, why there're only 5 years?

Comment: Well, *my* data is between 2000 and 2010, because I just created toy data that way. If I create toy data between 1800 and 2000, everything looks good. Do you have problems when you apply this approach to your own data?

Comment: Yes, also in my case the range is 2000-2008 even in the real interval is much bigger. Maybe I should change as.Date starting point in 1800?
If you want to check, here you can find the dataframe. Thank you very much. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41172284/GADUS.csv

Comment: Thx. If you read your data using `read.csv()` without specifying the `colClasses` argument, R believes that `datecollected` is a factor, which has funny consequences (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22811641/changing-factors-to-integers-without-changing-the-order-of-the-data). Simply change the `year.index` line above to `year.index <- (as.POSIXlt(as.character(dataset$datecollected),format="%Y-%m-%d")$year %/% 2)*2+1900`. I'd rather not edit the answer since I'd need to edit my toy data, too, and then it would be harder to understand for the next person coming here via Google.

Comment: It works! You save my day. Much obliged. I did not understand why before not, but with this new script all works.