# Changing factors to Integers without changing the order of the data

Tags: r

I have following data and trying change CCG and Pract to numbers so I can use stan or Winbugs...when I try to change it seems its changing the order of the data..
I want to change CCG and Pract to numbers without changing the order of the data...I tried hard but I couldn't do it.
I am struggling with this basic issue than writing Bugs codes....please help..

I have the following data

```
  CCG  pract  Deno Numer Points  Excep 
1 01C N81049   49    46      4       4           
2 01C N81022   28    26      4      23          
3 01C N81632   66    64      4       4          
4 01C N81069   15    14      4       3           
5 01C N81062   98    89      4       9          
6 01C N81033   31    28      4       9
```

I tried to change to integer using as.integer() and I am getting I am getting..

```
  CCG pract Deno Numer Points Excep
1  20  6621  160   144    41    36       
2  20  6594  130   117    41    18       
3  20  6698  179   164    41    36       
4  20  6640   57    46    41    25       
5  20  6633  214   191    41    62       
6  20  6605  137   119    41    62
```

By checking Deno and Numer it is clear the order of the data has been changed...Why CCG is not starting from 1?

I want

```
   CCG  pract  Deno Numer   Points Excep 
1 01C N81049   49    46      4         4           
2 01C N81022   28    26      4        23          
3 01C N81632   66    64      4         4          
4 01C N81069   15    14      4         3           
5 01C N81062   98    89      4         9          
6 01C N81033   31    28      4         9
```

change to something like this

```
  CCG  pract     Deno Numer    Points Excep 
1    1    1      49    46        4       4           
2    1    1      28    26        4      23          
3    1    1      66    64        4       4          
4    1    1      15    14        4       3          
5    1    1      98    89        4       9          
6    1    1      31    28        4       9
```

Please help me..

Comment: Relevel the factors so they're in the order they appear (use `unique` to get that), then convert to integer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert factor to integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798343/convert-factor-to-integer)

Answer (score 2):

In R, factors are internally represented as integers, linking to a table of the factor levels. AFAIK, these internal integers are assigned based on a *lexicographic* order of the factor levels, so 57 gets a higher code than 238.

`as.integer()` will extract this internal integer coding. As you found out, this is not very useful. (I honestly don't understand why R does this when applying `as.integer()` to factors that have integers as factor levels.)

Solution: first convert to character, then to integer. `as.integer(as.character(Deno))`

Comment: Another option to do this is `as.numeric(levels(f))[f]`; this is preferred by the help page, but admittedly is not as clear to understand.

Comment: when I try as.numeric(as.character(CCG))   I am getting a warning message:  NAs introduced by coercion.

Comment: @Vera: CCG cannot be interpreted as an integer, here my solution won't work. Have you tried Aaron's?